# What's the difference between the kernel boot parameters nohz_full and isolcpus=nohz

Tags: linux-kernel, kernel-parameters

When isolating CPU cores for jitter-sensitive processes it is common to use both boot parameters `nohz_full` and `isolcpus` (I know the latter is deprecated in favor of cpusets, but it's still around). `isolcpus` also has a `nohz` parameter. I wonder if it has the same effect as `nohz_full`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Initially, the **nohz_full** kernel parameter was meant to only (*) :

> set the specified list of CPUs whose tick will be stopped whenever
> possible.

When **isolcpus** was meant to (*) :

> Specify one or more CPUs to isolate from disturbances specified in the
> flag list

*Disturbance* depicts a much wider area than the timer tick only.
As a matter of fact, if work queues are shared among all CPUs and the scheduler algorithms must consequently run on all these CPUs for loadbalance's sake… this also consists in a disturbance nohz_full won't prevent from when isolcpus will.

[This patch](https://lore.kernel.org/lkml/1430928266-24888-5-git-send-email-fweisbec@gmail.com/) (from 2015) even acknowledged that :

> nohz_full is only useful with isolcpus also set, since otherwise the
> scheduler has to run periodically to try to determine whether to steal
> work from other cores.

And made so that :

> when booting with nohz_full=xxx on the command line, we should act as
> if isolcpus=xxx was also set, and set (or extend) the isolcpus set to
> include the nohz_full cpus.

Therefore… we can nowadays consider that :
if the specified sets of CPUs are identical, it is no longer necessary to specify both parameters.

---

(*) quoting *[The Linux kernel user’s and administrator’s guide](https://www.kernel.org/doc/html/v5.4/admin-guide/kernel-parameters.html)*

Comment: However they are not identical. We actually use nohz_full without isolcpus and manage the scheduling domains dynamically. - nohz_full manages the tick, - isolcpus=managed_irq,X manages interrupts and cgroups v2 partitions can be used to manage CFS scheduling domains.